# deleting records from a table where there is an inner join

Tags: sql

I am trying to delete records in one table based on records in another table. I am using an inner join. The code i am using is as follows;

```
 delete * from assets_l a, laptop_tracker b
 where a.serialno=b.serialno;
```

I am trying to delete all the records in the assets_l table that have a matching serial number to records in the laptop tracker table. Some help please?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That statement is product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gave you the idea to join? You want to delete from assets_l where exists a match in laptop_tracker. You can almost translate this word for word into SQL:

```
delete from assets_l
where exists (select * from laptop_tracker lt where lt.serialno = assets_l.serialno);
```

In other words: delete from assets_l where the serial number is also in laptop_tracker:

```
delete from assets_l
where serialno in (select serialno from laptop_tracker);
```

I'd go for the second statement (with the `IN` clause) for its simplicity. This is Standard SQL and should work in every RDBMS.